# C++ get network utilization like task manager

Tags: c++, windows, networking

Im trying to get the network adapter utilization as shown in task manager.
I've now tried to use WMI, and i'm able to get bytes received per second/ bytes sent per second. Is there any way to get the pre calculated value shown in task manager(0-100%), or can i use these to calculate that value?

[image]

```
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"),
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
        << " Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}


// Get the data from the query
IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
ULONG uReturn = 0;

while (pEnumerator)
{

    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);

    if (0 == uReturn)
    {
    break;
    }


    VARIANT vtProp;
    VariantInit(&vtProp);

    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    wcout << " network adapter : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);

    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"BytesReceivedPerSec", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);        
    wcout << " BytesReceivedPerSec  : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);

    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"BytesSentPerSec", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);        
    wcout << " BytesSentPerSec  : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);

    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Timestamp_Sys100NS", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    wcout << " Timestamp_Sys100NS  : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);




    pclsObj->Release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains the field `CurrentBandwidth`, with which you can compute the percentage.

```
float pct = (BytesReceivedPerSec * 100.f) / (CurrentBandwidth * 800.f)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this direction, however with this calculation im getting over 97% percent all the time even if the there is not much network traffic.

Comment: My bad, the default scale is -6... and in bits/s

Comment: Thank's for your support but im still not getting any values that make sense. I came over the article in the link below, even though that example is for C# it looks like that's the way its done for task manager. i will try this with C++https://web.archive.org/web/20080315235958/http://nayyeri.net/blog/how-to-calculate-network-utilization-in-net/